# Make ajax call to update Video Hits when showing Video

Tags: asp.net, jquery, fancybox

I am working on asp.net web page where i am showing you-tube videos using fancy-box.

So far it is working fine, I also need to make an ajax call to asp.net file `updateHits.aspx?VideoID=xyzxvtmiw`  so that i can update the hits/views for this video in the database (when someone clicks the thumbnail). I am not quite sure how to make this call when user click on the image thumbnail of a video on video.aspx page.

Below is part of my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Code to Reinitialize Fancybox script when using update panel START
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) { InitMyFancyBox(); }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        InitMyFancyBox();
    });

    function InitMyFancyBox() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".youtube").click(function () {
                // first, get the value from the alt attribute
                var newTitle = $(this).find("img").attr("alt"); // Get alt from image
                $.fancybox({
                    'padding': 0,
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    //'title': this.title, // we will replace this line
                    'title': newTitle,  //<--- this will do the trick
                    'width': 680,
                    'height': 495,
                    'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                    'type': 'swf',
                    'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    }
</script>


            <asp:Repeater ID="rptvideos" runat="server" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="single-video-wrapper">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hylnkvideo" CssClass="youtube"  NavigateUrl='<%# getVideoURL(Eval("VideoID"), Eval("VideoYoutubeID")) %>' runat="server">
                        <div class="video-image-wrapper">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgvideo" ImageUrl='<%# getVideoImagePath(Eval("VideoYoutubeID"), Eval("VideoYoutubeIcon")) %>'   AlternateText='<%# getVideoTitleDesc(Eval("VideoDate"),Eval("VideoTitle"),Eval("VideoDesc")) %>'  runat="server" CssClass="video-thumbnail" />
                        </div>
                       <div class="video-name">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblvideoName" CssClass="video-name-lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("VideoTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="video-issue">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblVideoIssue" CssClass="video-issue-lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#getIssuCode(Eval("IssueCode")) %>'></asp:Label>
                       </div>
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Based on the code above i am reinitializing fancy-box as i have updatePanel.

But i am not sure how i should make ajax call to  `updateHits.aspx?VideoID=xyzxvtmiw` so that i can update database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add your AJAX call to the click event:

```
function InitMyFancyBox() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".youtube").click(function () {
            // first, get the value from the alt attribute
            var newTitle = $(this).find("img").attr("alt"); // Get alt from image
            $.fancybox({
                //...
            });
            // your Ajax call here
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "updateHits.aspx?VideoID=xyzxvtmiw"
            });
            return false;
         });
    });
}
```

If you want the ajax call to be separate from the fancybox init you can just add another click handler somewhere else in your page:

```
$(".youtube").click(function () {
    // your Ajax call here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateHits.aspx?VideoID=xyzxvtmiw"
    });
}
```

Comment: you mean like `'href': 'updateHits.aspx?VideoID=xyzxvtmiw'` as i dont not any result from the ajax call it will just update ...

Comment: No, I mean via a seperate $.ajax() line. See the updated answer. If you want to know more about $.ajax, Google is your friend. ;)

Comment: It is not working for some reason, I am in debug mode & notice call to file is not being made..

Comment: @attice thanks it is working i was just calling a different file. It is working as required...